# UIButton has Blue Tint When Tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to make an UIButton turn my purple hex color with white text when users tap to choose Current Location, then make it switch back to a white background with purple text. However, I'm running into a problem where when I tap for the first time, my text has a blue tint behind the text. I have tried to set the tint to clear to try and fix the issue, but it makes the text disappear. What can I do to get this working? Thank you!

**My Issue**

[image]

**ServiceDetailController**

```
lazy var currentLocationButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Current Location", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkPurpleTint.cgColor
    button.setDimensions(height: 30, width: 30)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 30 / 2
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(currentLocationTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func currentLocationTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    if sender.isSelected {
       sender.backgroundColor = .darkPurpleTint
       sender.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
       sender.isSelected.toggle()
    } else {
       sender.backgroundColor = .white
       sender.setTitleColor(.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
       sender.isSelected.toggle()
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save yourself some code by taking advantage of the `.selected` state of the button...

```
lazy var currentLocationButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Current Location", for: [])
    
    // title color when normal
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkPurpleTint, for: .normal)
    
    // title color when selected
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .selected)
    
    // tint color clear removes the "blue box" when selected
    button.tintColor = .clear
    
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2

    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkPurpleTint.cgColor
    
    // don't know what you're doing here...
    //button.setDimensions(height: 30, width: 30)
    
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 30 / 2
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(currentLocationTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func currentLocationTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected.toggle()

    // change the background color
    sender.backgroundColor = sender.isSelected ? .darkPurpleTint : .white
    
}
```